# Как получить максимально контрастный цвет по отношению к другому?

Tags: алгоритм, веб-программирование

Допустим, есть красный цвет. Как получить цвет, максимально контрастный для него?

Есть какой-либо алгоритм, который позволяет решить эту задачу?

Comment: Могу предложить куда копать... Цвет в web это красный, зелёный и синий. RGB = ff ff ff= 255 255 255= белый цвет. 00 00 00 = черный цвет. Но с ходу сам не могу придумать алгоритм контрастности. Кстати, есть такая функция в less, можете посмотреть там.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение вот в этой [статье](https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/).

Код на JS:

```
  getContrastYIQ(hexcolor) {
    var r = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(1,2), 16);
    var g = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(3,2), 16);
    var b = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(5,2), 16);
    var yiq = ((r * 299) + (g * 587) + (b * 114)) / 1000;
    return (yiq >= 128) ? 'black' : 'white';
  }

  getContrastYIQ('#ffffff'); // вернет black
```

В зависимости от цвета, он вернет либо "black", либо "white" и эти цвета всегда будут контрастны по отношению к тому цвету, который был передан в функцию.

Comment: Т.е. простой перевод в стандартный черно-белый и выбор либо белого, либо черного...

Comment: @Harry ага. Это, конечно, не "абсолютно" контрастный цвет, но мне этот вариант подошёл даже лучше.